# How can I access the first 1MB of RAM in Windows programming (Protected Mode)?

Tags: c++, windows, ram, protected-mode

How can I access the first 1 MB of RAM directly in Windows programming (Protected Mode)?

For example to write to the video part.

Can I use DPMI to solve all problems?

Comment: If you're looking for graphics, DirectX is about as close as you get.

Comment: _"solve all problems"_? What specific problems are you talking about? May I suggest that you perhaps take a look at the [Stack Overflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Btw., what makes you think that the video adapter is mapping its memory area into the lowest 1 MB? What makes you think the video adapter's memory area even fits into 1 MB? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

No, a regular (=user-mode) application can't access directly the physical address space (the address space each application sees is a *virtual* address space, managed by the OS via the MMU). The whole point of having an operating system is to abstract the hardware details and present to applications a clean programmatic interface, if you want to draw onscreen you should use the graphic libraries provided by Windows (GDI, DirectX).

You *can* access almost any hardware resource if you write a driver that runs in kernel mode, but if you don't follow carefully the rules of Windows kernel-mode programming you are probably going to make the whole system crash with a BSOD in no time.

If you are talking about video RAM and DPMI I suppose you are coming from some book/tutorial about DOS-style programming (or even without any operating system at all); keep in mind that almost nothing of that stuff is applicable in the context of any modern operating system, because it's not only your code that is running, so you must cooperate and follow the rules/use the APIs of the OS.